# how to provide link dynamically to gridview and how to write code on click of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to give a link to every cell of every column and every row. and on click of it i want to create a new grid view. I was successfully able to give link to every cell of column dynamically but i am not able to find the event which is being triggered on click of that link in which i can write a code for catching the column and row value. and can use it further...

here is the code for generating the link dynamically...

```
protected void GDVReports_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();
            myLink.NavigateUrl = "ExitInt_DashBoard.aspx";
            if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                while (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    myLink.Controls.Add(cell.Controls[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myLink.Text = cell.Text;
            }
            cell.Controls.Add(myLink);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my grid view...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GDVReports" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CssClass="gridtable" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Font-Size="Small" OnRowDataBound="GDVReports_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GDVReports_SelectedIndexChanged">   
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is how i am binding it dynamically...

```
try
{
    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter daB = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct(Emp_Brand) from Emp", con);
    DataSet dsB = new DataSet();
    daB.Fill(dsB);
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

    SqlDataAdapter daY = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct DATEPART(yyyy,DOResignation) from Exit_Interview", con);
    DataSet dsY = new DataSet();
    daY.Fill(dsY);

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Brand", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < dsY.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(dsY.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(), typeof(int));
    }

    string[] s = new string[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < dsB.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // table.Rows.Add(dsB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(), s[0],s[1],s[2]);

        // string tempooo = dsB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < dsY.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
        {

            String s2 = "Select count(Sr_No) as '" + dsB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "' from Exit_Interview where Emp_Brand='" + dsB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "' AND YEAR(Date_Form_Created)='" + dsY.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() + "'";
            ds = new DataSet();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(s2, con);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            s[j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();


            //  dr[j] = s[j];
            //  table.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 10);
        }

        //dr[1] = s[0];
        //dr[2] = s[1];
        //dr[3] = s[2];
        int z = 1;
        DataRow dr;
        dr = table.NewRow();

        for (int j = 1; j < dsY.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1; j++)
        {
            dr[j] = s[j];
        }
        dr[0] = dsB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
        //  table.Rows.Add(dr);

        //                table.Rows.Add(dsB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),s[0],s[1],s[2]);
        //              table.Rows[0][1] = s[0];
    }
    GDVReports.DataSource = table;
    GDVReports.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('ERROR!!')</script>");
}
```

Comment: `OnRowDataBound` you created `Hyperlink` for each cell instead of that you could create `LinkButton` with `OnClick` event to fire. May this  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Dynamic-Button-LinkButton-and-ImageButton-in-ASP.Net.aspx  help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add the event on RowDataBound like this :

```
 protected void GDVReports_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
                    linkButton.Click += ViewDetails;
                    linkButton.Text= "Test"
                    cell.Controls.Add(linkButton);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then you can catch the event like this :

```
protected void ViewDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // catch your link ....
    LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton);
    GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
    string id = lnkView.CommandArgument;

    // write your code here ....

}
```

Comment: ayman barhoum, this isn't working the on row bound method is not recognizing the click event of mylink

Comment: @kr16 Yes because you are using HyperLink and this field does not have click event by default, you can use LinkButton instead.

Comment: yes i used link button now and tried executing it but its not going inside if loop after i click on a link

Comment: so what i did was used link button in the code... but i am not able to trigger the event ....

Comment: @kr16 : cell.Controls.Count  always equql 0 as you dont have any controls yet, i updated GDVReports_RowDataBound method now check my updates